# Rails can't match the existed route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.1

First I rake routes to check all the routes and make sure it exists in my app.

In my route.rb

```
resources :user do
  resource :account
  resource :addresses
end
```

And now everything is fine so far. I got some path helper method. Such as

```
user_addresses_path
```

this helper method works fine in everywhere(I mean it work in every view template)except one place. It can't work under my user's view template. I'll show you blow.

```
#it works here.
#this file is under app/view/address
<%= user_addresses_path(@user) %>    

#it doesn't work here.
#this file is under app/view/user
<%= user_addresses_path(@user) %>
```

Just for convenient, I don't paste all the codes in here.

But if you understand what I mean, you know, just tell me why is this happening.

Add comment if you want more detail.

Comment: Are you getting errors? Is `@user` `nil` ?

Comment: of course not nil. and the error is can't match the controller addresses. But it works in everywhere except there

Comment: This is isn't exactly similar to what I've seen before, but I wonder if it's having trouble with the fact that you pluralized `addresses` in your routes file, but set is as a single resource. Doesn't really explain the conditional behaviour you're setting though.

Comment: you see the user_addresses_path works everywhere that means the helper method is absolutely correct. But it just simply won't work under the user view template. Does it not weird?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is the way you've got the address route defined as a nested route for the user. Specifically, in the [rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-url_for) it states:

> Passing a record (like an Active Record or Active Resource) instead of a Hash as the options parameter will trigger the named route for that record. The lookup will happen on the name of the class. So passing a Workshop object will attempt to use the workshop_path route. If you have a nested route, such as admin_workshop_path you’ll have to call that explicitly (it’s impossible for url_for to guess that route).

In other words, because the route being referred to is defined as a nested route, rails can't guess the route. Since addresses are nested inside the user, it can guess the user when on a specific address, but not the address when up at the user level.

Also, is it possible that what you have is a 'one-to-many' user-to-address relationship? If that's the case, then your `resource` might need to be `resources` (plural) in your routes file.

```
resources :user do
  resource :addresses
end
```

gives you:

```
user_addresses         POST   /user/:user_id/addresses(.:format)        {:action=>"create", :controller=>"addresses"}
new_user_addresses     GET    /user/:user_id/addresses/new(.:format)    {:action=>"new", :controller=>"addresses"}
edit_user_addresses    GET    /user/:user_id/addresses/edit(.:format)   {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"addresses"}
                       GET    /user/:user_id/addresses(.:format)        {:action=>"show", :controller=>"addresses"}
                       PUT    /user/:user_id/addresses(.:format)        {:action=>"update", :controller=>"addresses"}
                       DELETE /user/:user_id/addresses(.:format)        {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"addresses"}
```

but,

```
resources :user do
  resources :addresses
end
```

gives you:

```
                    POST   /user/:user_id/addresses(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"addresses"}
new_user_address    GET    /user/:user_id/addresses/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"addresses"}
edit_user_address   GET    /user/:user_id/addresses/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"addresses"}
user_address        GET    /user/:user_id/addresses/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"addresses"}
                    PUT    /user/:user_id/addresses/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"addresses"}
                    DELETE /user/:user_id/addresses/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"addresses"}
```

Notice that the second option (plural) gives you routes to be able to address multiple addresses for each user, whereas the singular route only gives you a single address.